# Mobile Web App with Printing Report

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-mobile

I'm going to develop a web application in html5 and jquery mobile with php and mysql for registering restaurant orders to use with android palm and desktop computer!

My problem is to print directly the report of the order in the kitchen when the waiter register the order; i think to use [Google Cloud Print](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/sendJobs?hl=it) setting up a kitchen printer..

How do you think of this?? Do you have any example?

Another Question: is there a "mini-printer" to use directly without connect it to a pc? i wish furthermore print to A6 page type or smaller.

Thank you in advance for your attention and please sorry for my bad english!!

Comment: Do not use Google Cloud Print. It is an overkill for your application and requires internet connection. What will happen if there is an Internet outage? Your second question is off topic. There are Bluetooth printers available that don't require a PC, but you won't be able to drive them from a web site.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I had not thought of this possibility..

Answer (score 0):

You could write a desktop application that checks the database for new orders every x minutes/seconds and sends new orders to a printer if it finds any.

Comment: Could You give me any axample of this?

Comment: No example unfortunately. But you could look into using C#.NET (if your using Windows) and research 'C# Printing' and 'C# MySQL'. Combine these two topics and you should be able to come up with a solution.